# self referential association with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` and `Address` models. A user may have many addresses and one as default. I currently use this that works

```
# User.rb
belongs_to :default_address, class_name: "Address", foreign_key: :default_address_id
```

Now I made the Address `belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true`.

My question is how to tell this default_address self association to use the `addressable` instead of going directly to the Address class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `has_one` instead of `belongs_to` on `User.rb`

```
has_one :default_address, class_name: "Address", as: :addressable, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :default_address
```